# PlantUML Activity diagram new (beta) syntax with Short Codes to reference earlier activity?

Tags: uml, plantuml

I created a activity diagram using the legacy PlantUML Activity syntax (https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-legacy):

```
@startuml

(*) --> "Request created" as Request
Request --> "Review request" as Review 

if "is Accepted?" then
    --> [Yes] "Assign" 
    if "is Urgent" then
        --> [Yes] "In Development`" 
        --> "Engineer Assigned"  
    else
        --> [No] "Backlog" as Backlog 
        Backlog --> Review

    endif
else 
    --> [No] "Won’t Do"
endif
@enduml
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Legacy syntax diagram]

I am now trying to recreate this diagram using the new (beta) syntax (https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta) but am having difficulty replicating the capabilities of Short Codes to reference and return to an earlier activity step.

```
@startuml

start
:Request created;
:Review request;

if (is Accepted?) then (Yes)
    :Assign;

    if (is Urgent) then (Yes)
        
        :In Development;
        :Engineer Assigned;
        stop
    else (No)
        :Backlog;
        ' HERE I WOULD LIKE BACKLOG TO HAVE 
        ' A BACKWARD ARROW POINTING UP TO 
        ' "REVIEW REQUEST"
    endif
else (No)
    :Won’t Do;
    stop
endif
@enduml
```

[image: New syntax diagram]

Is it possible to achieve the same diagram with the new syntax as I created with the old?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that :

```
@startuml
start

:Request created;

while (Review request?) is (accepted)
     :Assign;
     if (is Urgent ?) then (Yes)
        :In Development;
        :Engineer Assigned;
        stop
    else (No)
        :Backlog;
    endif
endwhile (not accepted)
:Won't Do;
stop
@enduml
```

producing :

[image]

... which is as illegal as your first diagram because there are two input flows to *Review request* and we are not in the case where one is the *decisionInputFlow* and the other the *primary incoming edge* (see §15.3.3.6
Decision Nodes page 390 of [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1)), a *merge node* must be used before the *decision node*.

Comment: I still do not understand why people loose their time to use PlantUML when the goal is just to make a picture, and of course it is worst when the result is invalid in UML. For me better to save time using  any standard drawing tool, also allowing to make the picture as expected and valid, without being limited by PlantUML choices/capacities. To implement PlantUML is without any contest an interesting and not easy problem, but to use it is a non sense for me. Of course for people wanting to use UML including making diagrams rather than to just draw pictures the UML modelers are here for that.

Comment: Why have Latex when you have Word?

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I used Latex by hand in past, but it is faster and more practical to use a WYSIWYG editor for a human ... including when that text editor produces Latex ;-)

Comment: It's about balance. I doubt you'd use Word to write a math paper in Word even if it's possible technically. Same is with tools like PlantUML - pictures are essentially a one-time product that aren't intended to be modified, maintained etc. If you plan to change, extend, embed the diagram - I don't think that using pictures will make your life easier.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I am not a mathematician but I know the capacities of Latex to produce pretty formulas, and not only that. But concerning the initial topic I persist to think to use PlantUML is one of the less practical ways ... and worst producing diagram not compatible with UML standard